# How to extract the parameters from the output of a formated string in Java

Tags: java, parsing, format

I am trying to parse the output of a program and extract the parameters used to generated these results. The output are in the form of sentences generated from the format function in Python e.g.:

- Opening browser 'Google Chrome' to base url 'https://https://stackoverflow.com'. is genereated from Opening browser '%s' to base url '%s'
- Clicking element 'xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), "cc-btn cc-dismiss")]'. is genereated from Clicking element '%s'.

I want to extract the initial input parameters in the format function. My function would look something like:

```
private List<String> extractParameters(String output, String format){
  // code would come here
}
```

The function takes as input the generated string and the format string that was used to generate it (e.g. "Clicking element '%s'.") and returns a sorted list of the parameters that were used (e.g. "xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), "cc-btn cc-dismiss")]")

I started working on a method using regex, but I have many formats to manage and not being a regex expert the solution I am moving towards to is really ugly and non maintainable. So the question is:

Is there any elegant way to achieve my goal in an elegant way in Java?

Comment: The better approach is not to do this at all. Instead, edit the original code that is generating this formatted text, to produce machine-readable text like JSON or XML, instead or in addition.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to analyse data that were generated for months, I cannot rerun them, I just have the output stream so this is my input, I cannot change it. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex should do the trick but you should be sure they are optimized and well written. For your above examples I made a simple line analyzer based on regex patterns:

```
class RegexLineAnalyzer {

    private List<Pattern> patterns = new ArrayList<>();

    public RegexLineAnalyzer() {
        patterns.add(Pattern.compile("^Opening browser '(.+)' to base url '(.+)'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
        patterns.add(Pattern.compile("^Clicking element '(.+)'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
        // add other patterns
    }

    public List<String> extractParameters(String line) {
        for (Pattern pattern : patterns) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>(matcher.groupCount());
                for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    parameters.add(matcher.group(i + 1));
                }

                return parameters;
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

I assume that log files are split on lines. How to read and split files by lines efficiently you can find on this [page](https://www.java-success.com/processing-large-files-efficiently-java-part-1/).

Example usage of above analyzer could be like below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("Opening browser 'Google Chrome' to base url 'https://https://stackoverflow.com'.");
        lines.add("Clicking element 'xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), \"cc-btn cc-dismiss\")]'.");

        RegexLineAnalyzer regexLineAnalyzer = new RegexLineAnalyzer();
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line + " => " + regexLineAnalyzer.extractParameters(line));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Opening browser 'Google Chrome' to base url 'https://https://stackoverflow.com'. => [Google Chrome, https://https://stackoverflow.com]
Clicking element 'xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), "cc-btn cc-dismiss")]'. => [xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), "cc-btn cc-dismiss")]]
```

**EDITED**
I thought you have a list of patterns you can match to each line. In case you need to guess a pattern and after that analyse it and find arguments you can use a simpler solution based on `split` function. We have to assume that each line contains even number of `'` character. We would have a problem with lines like: `Jon's browser is 'IE'` or `User last name is 'O'Reilly'` or we could face `User's last name is 'O'Reilly'`. Simple implementation could look like below:

```
class SplitLineAnalyzer {

    public List<String> extractParameters(String line) {
        final String regex = "'";
        final String[] split = line.split(regex);
        if (split.length % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Line contains unexpected number of parts. Hard to guess pattern for line = " + line);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i += 2) {
            args.add(split[i]);
            split[i] = "%s";
        }

        Arrays.stream(split).reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + regex + s2).ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("Possible pattern: " + s));

        return args;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("Opening browser 'Google Chrome' to base url 'https://https://stackoverflow.com'.");
        lines.add("Clicking element 'xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), \"cc-btn cc-dismiss\")]'.");
        lines.add("'Firefox' is used by user 'Tom'.");
        lines.add("Lines like this' could be broken.");
        lines.add("User's first name is 'Jerry'.");
        lines.add("User's last name is 'O'Reilly'");

        SplitLineAnalyzer regexLineAnalyzer = new SplitLineAnalyzer();
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line + " => " + regexLineAnalyzer.extractParameters(line));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Possible pattern: Opening browser '%s' to base url '%s'.
Opening browser 'Google Chrome' to base url 'https://https://stackoverflow.com'. => [Google Chrome, https://https://stackoverflow.com]

Possible pattern: Clicking element '%s'.
Clicking element 'xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), "cc-btn cc-dismiss")]'. => [xpath=.//a[contains(normalize-space(@class), "cc-btn cc-dismiss")]]

Possible pattern: '%s' is used by user '%s'.
'Firefox' is used by user 'Tom'. => [Firefox, Tom]

Line contains unexpected number of parts. Hard to guess pattern for line = Lines like this' could be broken.
Lines like this' could be broken. => []

Line contains unexpected number of parts. Hard to guess pattern for line = User's first name is 'Jerry'.
User's first name is 'Jerry'. => []

Line contains unexpected number of parts. Hard to guess pattern for line = User's last name is 'O'Reilly'
User's last name is 'O'Reilly' => []
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, it looks very promising, but my issue was that i didn't want to hardcode the patterns since the number might end up in the hundreds. But it might be the easiest solution.